# Puppeteer: TimeoutError: waiting for selector

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am waiting for a selector to load on the page but I also need to handle cases where there is a timeout.

Currently, my script stops execution and does not continue. How can i handle error cases of timeout and still proceed with execution.

below is my relevant code.

```
    const newPagePromise = new Promise(res => browser.on('targetcreated', target => res(target.page())));
    for(const dataWorkSheet of dataWorkSheetsArray) {
       try{
         await page.evaluate(async () => {
          await $('.export--popup a').click();
         });
         const exportPopup = await newPagePromise;
         await Promise.all([
          await exportPopup.click('#data-0'),
          await exportPopup.waitForSelector('.cLink'),
         ]);
       } catch(e) {

       }
    }
```

How can i ensure, my loop continues even when there is a timeout error when executing `waitForSelector`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could play with the catch of the promise:

```js
await Promise.all([
  await exportPopup.click('#data-0'),
  await exportPopup.waitForSelector('.cLink').catch(error => console.log('failed to wait 
 for the selector'),
 ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can considering add some more time to wait the element so that the script will continue to run?

```
await exportPopup.waitForSelector('.cLink', {timeout: 120000})
```